# How to set auto as min-height using jQuery for div?

Tags: jquery, css

I have following div element which receives `min-height` at the time of page load.

```
<div id="main_div" style="min-height: 2000px">
</div>
```

But I do have one select box on same page and onChange event of it I am loading other contents in `main_div` div element.

Now problem is `min-height` always set to `2000px` and I don't know in advance that what should I set to `min-height: ?` when `$.ajax` call finishes?

I am doing like below on `success()`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/url/',
    data: {param: param},
    cache: false,
    success: function(htmlData) {
        $("#main_div").html(htmlData);
        $("#main_div").css("min-height", 'auto');
    }
});
```

But it's not working. I don't know height of new contents which are just loaded in div.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Do you really need to use `min-height` property here?!

Comment: @A.Wolff, Yes. I must.

Comment: @NullPointer - why? Why not just let the HTML content dictate the height of the element? From your code, it seems like what you are doing anyway. Also, if you want `min-height` to be `auto` - just set `min-height` to 0.

Comment: @Adam, it's working like charm! (y) but how?

Comment: Read up on what min-height is and what it does. You probably don't need to use it at all. If you don't have a min-height (or height) specified on your element, then the height of your element will be dictated by it's contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function you can simply set min-height to empty, like this:

```
$("#main_div").css("min-height", '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.scrollHeight` to get height of div content. Use the same to set the height/min-height.Try this:

```
$("#main_div").css("min-height", $('#main_div')[0].scrollHeight);
```

Comment: But what happens is that in first page load page comes with 15 divs and in ajax call it just comes with 5 elements so your solution taking scrollheight of previous div's height.

Comment: @NullPointer: what all contents do you have in `main_div `. does it also have images.

Comment: Yes. It has images too.

Comment: @NullPointer: Then you need to write the code on load of images. see this `https://api.jquery.com/load-event/`

Answer (score 1):

min-height: length|initial|inherit;

There is not "auto" value for this property

[see min-height property description](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

Answer (score 0):

min-height: length|initial|inherit;

auto is not a value for min-height.

[CHECK HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

[image]